# Gstream MonoDeveloper

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gstreamer

I would like to develop an application using `monodevelop`.
Since I need to playback audio and video with Gstreamer# (in fact I have to use Gstreamer-#), I did my best to figure out how I can do this, but unfortunately, I have not found any suitable link.

If anyone knows something I'll appreciate it if you share it with me.

Comment: Do you mean MonoDevelop the C# IDE or monodeveloper the C# library? Also, it is not clear what you are asking, could you try rephrasing your question?

Comment: @ArtB The first part of your comment is not clear either. You most certainly meant, [**Mono Framework**](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page), i.e. the open source, cross-platform, implementation of C# and the CLR that is binary compatible with Microsoft .NET Framework.

Comment: @monocoder From the subsequent edit it looks like he intended the IDE. I was originally going to correct his question but I discovered that there was a library called "mono-developer" which he could have meant.

Answer (score 1):

Like the doc says, you need to reference gstreamer-sharp.dll, which in turn requires gstreamersharpglue-0.10.dll in the same dir.

```
Gst.Application.Init(); // First init GStreamer - important!!
var pipeDescription = "playbin uri=myVid.avi name=myBin";
var pipeline = Gst.Parse.Launch(pipeDescription) as Gst.Bin; //Launch Pipeline
var someElementInPipe = pipeline.GetChildByName("myBin") as Gst.Element;
pipeline.SetState(Gst.State.Playing);
```

----OR use ElementFactory for manual pipe-construction----

```
Gst.Application.Init();
var pipeline = new Gst.Pipeline();
var elementA = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("someElement");
var elementB = Gst.ElementFactory.Make("someElement");
pipeline.Add(elementA, elementB);
elementA.Link(elementB);
pipeline.SetState(Gst.State.Playing);
```

For more examples check out the following tests:
http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp/tree/tests

Comment: thanks for the `Gst.Application.Init();`, I used one day to find out why my result of  `Gst.ElementFactory.Make` is always null and I found the answer here!! thanks so much